# Reverse tunnel commands through ssh?

Tags: ssh

I'm looking for a way to easily send commands **back** to my local computer, while connected to a remote host via ssh. Is this doable via tunnelling? Both systems are UNIXen.

For instance, I am connected to a remote host and through some alias "backwards" I want to do:

`user@remote $ backwards echo hi`

And the local machine would execute `echo hi`

Comment: Are you on a Unix system?

Comment: Yes, I am. Both ends in fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard SSH implementations do not provide this functionality. You will have to connect back to your local computer:

```
remote$ ssh "${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}" echo hi
```

If you are behind a NAT, you can use SSH "remote forwarding" to make the connection:

```
local$ ssh -R 23456:localhost:22 remote
remote$ ssh -P 23456 localhost echo hi
```

(With `-R`, "localhost:22" is the *client's* "localhost".)